# How to pass the javascript variable value to php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc(lang){
    var ll = lang;              
    //alert(ll);
    }
</script>
```

my html code

```
<form  method="post" action="mypage.php?>">
   <div>    
    <input type='image' src='/images/flags/us.png' name='US' value='en_EN' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/>   
<input type='image' src='/images/flags/it.png' name='IT' value='it_IT' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/> 
<input type='image' src='/images/flags/fr.png' name='FR' value='fr_FR' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/> 
    </div>
```

now how can i send the javascript `var ll` value to *mypage.php*

Actually I want the image alt value to pass it, How it is possible please give some idea..

Comment: I recommend jQuery AJAX and a bit of googling or to consider a form since you are submitting data.

Comment: Read through the questions listed as "Related" on the panel on the right. There are plenty of similar questions already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a hidden field inside the `<form>`

```
<input type="hidden" name="ll" id="ll">
```

in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc(lang){
        var ll=document.getElementById('ll');
        ll.value=lang;
    }
</script>
```

and then you have `ll` in PHP, when you submit the form.

---

### update

I guess you wonder if you have links instead of a form, like this? :

```
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="images/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT" /></a>
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="images/flags/fr.png" alt="fr" /></a>
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="images/flags/us.png" alt="en_EN" /></a>
```

And you just want to reload the page with `ll` containing the desired language code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.lang').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    document.location.href='mypage.php?ll='+lang;
});
</script>
```

Will reload your page, eg ex `mypage.php?ll=it_IT`. As with the form accessible in mypage.php through `$_GET['ll']`

Using jQuery here, since you have it on your tag-list (and it was the far easiest / fastest to produce :)

Comment: thanks a lot. Its work perfectly to my task. thank you so much.

Comment: hi david, I have one more query to you if i use anchor tag and href class like this mean how can get the my requirement               '<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="/images/flags/it.png" alt="it_IT" /></a>
<a href="#" class='lang'><img src="images/flags/fr.png" alt="fr" /></a>' will you help this one? thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your form, and use a hidden input to be posted to your php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunc(lang){
        //var ll = lang;              
        document.my_form.my_var.value=lang;
    }
</script>


<form name="my_form" method="post" action="mypage.php">
   <div>    
      <input type='image' src='/images/flags/us.png' name='US' value='en_EN' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/>   
      <input type='image' src='/images/flags/it.png' name='IT' value='it_IT' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/> 
      <input type='image' src='/images/flags/fr.png' name='FR' value='fr_FR' onclick='MyFunc(this.value)'/> 
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="my_var">
</form>
```

In your PHP file you can retrieve your data in $_POST array:

```
$my_data=$_POST["my_var"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try use Json:

1 - First. Save your page in PHP.
2 - Second. Modify your function in Javascript

Example

```
    var ll = lang;


            //caminho do ar



       $.getScript("http://www.site.com.br/busca_dados3.php?value="+ll, function(){

}
```

In this case, you want to create a file called 'busca_dados3.php' who receive the variables in $_REQUEST['value'];

You need Jquery to.