# How to pass php parameter from java-script template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a code below, which display image name on UI by reading it from the folder where those images are uploaded,

These image names are displaying using a [java-script template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl), I want to pass that name to a php function  in order to check its status by hitting the db by the image name..

Here is how the image name is displaying in UI:

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">

        <td>
           <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
              <!----- new update -------->
                  var a= file.name;
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/tripvioapp/trips/showStatus/",
                        dataType: "text",
                        data: {image_name: a,trip_id: '2'},
                        success: function(msg){ 
                              alert(msg);//how can i display this value in this place
                       }

                     });
        </td>

    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Basically, i have integrated  [file upload with Codeigniter(php framework)](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1.4)  From this tutorial

---

**What i tried so far**

i tried passing `{%=file.name%}` as below

```
$this->tripmodel->getImageStatusByUidName('\"{%=file.title%}\"',"2"); //calling php function
```

**Result:** instead of passing value from`{%=file.name%}` , its passing as it is.

**Expected (as it should work internally like this:)**

```
$this->tripmodel->getImageStatusByUidName("imageName.jpg","2");
```

Can anyone help me with this,please?

Comment: Please consider writing comment, if you down-vote. I don't know the reason of down-vote ?, is my question is not clear?

Comment: refer this link please. hope it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614270/how-to-pass-the-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put php code betwee 
somthing like

```
    <?php
    $this->tripmodel->getImageStatusByUidName( "{%=file.name%}","2");
    ?>
```

play around with it. i have not tested it

Comment: what is the error?. can you post updated source code?

Comment: some time php syntax error and sometime its simply passing the complete {%=file.title%} instead of value  .... And please edit your question with full model path `$this->tripmodel-> ....` because the function which we are calling is in some other file & class  .  If i know just how to pass the the file name , then my problem will solve

Comment: Or can you store this ({%=file.name%})  as javascript variable ? , eg. var fn={%=file.name%};   , so that i can easily call an ajax function

Comment: i updated my question, using ajax, i am able to give alert with correct value but how can i display the value in the same place where i  am giving alert?

Comment: i checked this is passing value to my model but now i have another problem, because we are mixing javascript & php its not returning value from model to display, i have asked a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049395/unable-to-return-single-column-value-while-running-and-calling-a-model-function

Comment: Please can you edit your question by correcting between spelling in question, please