# Pass Javascript Variable Value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to access javascript variable inside PHP. How Can I do this?

below is my javascript onClick of button I am getting value in alert.

```
$(".check").click(function(){
  var priceee = document.getElementById("total-price").value;
  //alert(priceee);
});
```

Comment: you need to use ajax

Comment: PHP = Server Side, JavaScript = Client Side. Server Side != Client Side therefore as suggested above you need to use JavaScript on the client side to call a PHP script on the server side via AJAX.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone  You are Correct Can you please provide some code example.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the price value, AJAX is very easy via jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789283/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614270/how-to-pass-the-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable

Comment: Thank You Everyone for Suggestion Let me try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try below to send the JS data to PHP via AJAX,

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'yourphppage.php',
   data: { 
      'totalprice' : $("#total-price").val(), 
   },
   success: function(response){
   }

  })

In yourphppage.php,

  echo $_POST['totalprice'];
```

Comment: Your Suggestion Works ...Thank you Man

Comment: @webmenstor, Glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX call to perform this either using the POST or GET Method as said by phpuser. For this to work you must be running it on a server so either on your local machine (localhost) using something like XAMPP or on an actual server.

Here is an example on how to write it.

```
$(function () {
$(".check").click(function(){
    var priceee = $("#total-price").val();

});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'file.php', //your php page
    data: {
        price: pricee
    },
    success: function (response) {
        //the code you want to execute once the response from the php is successful
    },
    error: function () {
        //error handling (optional)
    }
});
```

});

Your PHP page (in this example file.php)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    //now your variable is set. as $price in php
    echo $price; //returns price as response back to jQuery
}
```

Hope this helps, more information in the jQuery Ajax call documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Spalqui

Comment: There are shorter ways of writing the AJAX call by using the get() or post().